# JSON data array query

Tags: mysql, sql, json

i am using jsonTable to parse the data in to the Google table and it is working fine. now i have a problem to add multiple queries at the same time and display the data only in two columns of array which is already defined. here is my code:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT reg.`oilchange`-SUM(gs.`Distance`) AS Nextoilchange FROM gs INNER JOIN reg ON (gs.`DeviceId`=25) AND (reg.`DeviceId`=25) INNER JOIN LOG ON TIME BETWEEN DATE(log.`lastoilchange`) AND CURDATE()")
or die(mysql_error()); 

$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
 array('label' => 'Vehicle', 'type' => 'number'),
array('label' => 'Distance Left', 'type' => 'number')

);
$rows = array();
while ($nt = mysql_fetch_array($data))

{

$temp = array();

$temp[] = array('v' => 'Nextoilchange');
$temp[] = array('v' =>$nt['Nextoilchange']);

// insert the temp array into $rows
$rows[]['c'] = $temp;

}
$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
```

my first problem is this i want to add multiple queries in $data and each query gives one result. and my next problem is i want to display the data of multiple queries in above column defined as Distance left. and in vehicle column i want to add static data like above in $temp(1st row). i have searched a lot and i am confused how to do this. Please help me i want to display the table like this:

```
Vehicle            Distance Left

nextoilchange      500
nextfilter         300
nextcheckup        400
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not tested this . If not not work try something like this .

```
<?php 

$data[1] = mysql_query("SELECT reg.`oilchange`-SUM(gs.`Distance`) AS Nextoilchange FROM gs INNER JOIN reg ON (gs.`DeviceId`=25) AND (reg.`DeviceId`=25) INNER JOIN LOG ON TIME BETWEEN DATE(log.`lastoilchange`) AND CURDATE()")
or die(mysql_error());
$data[2] = mysql_query("SELECT reg.`oilchange`-SUM(gs.`Distance`) AS Nextoilchange FROM gs INNER JOIN reg ON (gs.`DeviceId`=25) AND (reg.`DeviceId`=25) INNER JOIN LOG ON TIME BETWEEN DATE(log.`lastoilchange`) AND CURDATE()")
or die(mysql_error());

$table[1]['cols'] = array(array('label' => 'Vehicle', 'type' => 'number'),array('label' => 'Distance Left', 'type' => 'number'));
$table[2]['cols'] =  array(array('label' => 'Vehicle', 'type' => 'number'),array('label' => 'Distance Left', 'type' => 'number'));

foreach($table as $key=>$eachtable)
{
    $cols = $eachtable['cols'];

    while ($nt = mysql_fetch_array($newdata))
    {

        foreach($cols as  $key1=>$each_col)
        {
            if($each_col['label'] == $nt)  //you have match the conditions
            {
                $row[$key1] = $nt['yourvalue'];
            }
            else
            {
                $row[$key1] = $nt['yourvalue1'];
            }
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
    }
    $table[$key]['rows'] = $rows;
}
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i have edited my post and now i have mentioned how table looks like. your code is helpful but i am confused because in Vehicle column i want to display the string values which are not stored in database and query results will be showed in Distance left column. Please tell me how can i do this?